# Variable values not getting into inner for loop

Tags: python, numpy

My inner for loop is not using new values from the outer loop.
What's wrong, and how do I fix it?

```
import numpy as np
a = 0.0000001
b = 15.
d = 0.1
TOL = 1.0e-6
a1 = []
dd = 0.1
da1 = []
for i in range(0,10):
    def f(v):
        return np.cosh(d * v) - (1./v) * np.sinh(d * v) - 1.
    FA = f(a)
    FB = f(b)
    for I in range(0,1000):
        p = a + (b - a) / 2.0
        FP = f(p)
        if FA == 0 or (b - a)/2.0 < TOL:
            break        
        I = I + 1
        if FA * FP > 0:
            a = p
            FA = FP
        if FA * FP < 0:
            b = p
    a1.append(p) 
    da1.append(d)
    d = d + dd
print a1
print da1
```

Here is a second implementation.  Variable **d** shows new values, but the inner loop keeps giving me the same result result, like it is not registering the new **d** value.

```
import numpy as np
a = 0.00001
a1 = []
dd = 0.1
da = 1.e-5
d = 0.1
yvs=[]
ds = []
EE = []
while d <= 1.:
    dnew = d
    print dnew
    for i in range(0,1000000):
        dnew = d
        yv = np.cosh(dnew * a) - (1./a) * np.sinh(dnew * a) - 1.
        yvs.append(yv)
        a = a + da
        a1.append(a)
        i = i + 1
    for ii in range(0,999999):
        As = (a1[ii]+a1[ii+1])/2.
        E = -1. * As**2    
        if yvs[ii]*yvs[ii+1] < 0:
            EE.append(E)
            print As, E
        ii = ii + 1
    d = dnew + dd
```

Comment: Why are you defining a method inside of a loop? There's no way that efficient.

Comment: That's illegible. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and please edit that code into your question.

Comment: Those tiny, inscrutable variable names remind me of the TI BASIC programs I hand-copied from magazines into my [TI-99/4A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_Instruments_TI-99/4A) back in the 1980s.  Self-documenting names really are worth the extra keystrokes, especially if you ever have to do more work on the code later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted my earlier answer; it's not the main problem you're having.

You traced the wrong values: **d** and **dnew** do, indeed, change.  However, they are not part of the data flow for the values you're worried about.

In the upper program, **d** depends exclusively on its starting value and increment value, both of them 0.1, and **dd** doesn't change.  **p** depends exclusively on the values of **a** and **b**, which also don't change.

Yes, you do some nice work to compute FA, FB, FP -- but then you hit the bottom of the loop, you don't save them anywhere, and then you overwrite tehm on the next loop.

If the lower program, you have the same problem with **As** and **E**: you never change the parameters on which they depend (that's all in **yvs**, which you never print out), so the outputs are the same on every loop.

Since you are using one- and two-letter variables and haven't documented your code, I don't have a good idea of how to fix this: I have little idea what your program is supposed to do, although it appears to want to converge some computational series.